# Svelte reactive statements won't fire until after HMR update

Tags: reactive-programming, sveltekit

I'm writing a large svelte app (HMR via vite), and at some point, something started blocking the reactive statements.  It seems that the events don't fire, although somethings update (like stores etc.)

What's interesting is that if I make any change that effects HMR (so I change a property from true to false, save it, then change it back from false to true) the update to that one .svelte file resets something, and everything starts working correctly from then on.

If I was only working on my PC, this would be fine, but I need to build and publish to a non-HMR environment.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem in a condensed way to share any code snippet.

I'm looking for the following:

1. Some way to trace the problem. (I don't see anything interesting in the vite logs during 'npm run dev')
2. Some way to accomplish the same sort of 'reset' of the reactive events similar to how the HMR update is.

Comment: Did you get a JS error from code in the template? It kind of breaks Svelte so it won't update after.

Comment: I am getting a JS error about a missing module that I see in the vite logs.  I'm working to track that down.    I thought perhaps that might be the culprit.   However the 'missing' module works just fine, even when the reactive statements don't.   (And it continues to work after I've use the HMR work-around.)

Restating that idea:
If I'm running a svelte app and it runs into a JS error 'way down the line' it might stop some of the 'reactive statements' and events from triggering.   Then, an HMR update to any of the files in the project might trigger some sort of 'state reset?'

Comment: Follow Up here:
I found which part of my svelte project was causing the blockage.   I'm using carbon-components, and on this one multiselect component, it doesn't like to be populated 'after the fact.'     (If I hard-code the same values it works fine...it's just the sending them in later that's problematic.)

Another developer told me they were getting visible HMR errors, that led them to believe I simply had too many reactive elements in my code, like I had reached some sort of limit.      However, I've never once been able to get those errors to show for me.

Comment: If there is a problem with Carbon components, consider opening an [issue in the repo](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/issues) if there isn't one already.